# Is the deletion of a constructor inherited?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, constructor

Using the keyword `delete` you can prevent the compiler from automatically adding standard implementations of certain constructors.

Is this deletion inherited to subclasses?

Comment: Why dont u just write a simple test

Comment: @texasbruce what kind of test and how?

Comment: Maybe I got you wrong, but if I understand it correctly, u can make a class, set one constructor as delete, and inherit this class and try to create using the constructor

Comment: @texasbruce well empirical experiments are fun and all, but in C++, I am seeking for more definitive answers. A lot of mistakes programmers make in this language come from mere apparent knowledge. But no, you didn't get me wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently, but I wouldn't exactly say that the attribute is inheirited.  It is due to the fact that the compiler generated derived class constructor uses the base class constructor.  For example, the compiler generated default constructor of a derived class uses the default constructor of the base class. So if the base class default constructor does not exist, for whatever reason (whether it was explicitly deleted, or some other reason), the compiler cannot generate a default constructor for the derived class. But this doesn't stop you from creating your own constructor for the derived class which uses a different base class constructor than the one which was deleted.

Comment: `But this doesn't stop you from creating your own constructor for the derived class which uses a different base class constructor than the one which was deleted.` Unfortunately, yes. So there's no easy way to prevent subclasses from being copy-constructible.

Answer (score 0):

> Using the keyword `delete` you can prevent the compiler from automatically adding standard implementations of certain constructors.

Well, not really. Yes, it does accomplish that purpose. But it also prevents *you* from implementing that constructor yourself.

Constructors are not inherited, in general. Deleting a constructor in the base class does *not* cause the corresponding constructor in the derived class to be deleted too. It *does* force the compiler to implicitly define the corresponding constructor in the derived class as deleted---but only if you don't define it yourself.